# Should I 'seed' questions, particularly on beta sites, when I don't necessarily have that question myself?

Tags: support, asking-questions, beta-phase

I've come across this a few times: an opportunity to help 'seed' an SE site (particularly a beta site) by asking a question that seems to be a good question, but isn't asked yet on the site.

It might be something I thought of and briefly wondered about, but apart from that isn't a "real problem or question I have encountered".

Given that SE sites are about building a repository of great content, should I ask still ask my question?

Or, given I could be wasting someone's time responding when the answer isn't actually going to help me, should I refrain?

I ask particularly about beta sites because I know it's important to build great content during the beta phase, but I am also interested in the applicability of this to graduated sites too (and no, this isn't a seed question itself - I've encountered this conundrum several times!)